# Obtaining an Expression's Position and Length within the Text Being Parsed

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

As my ANTLR-generated parser executes, I want to raise an event containing the position and length of the expression being evaluated so that I can highlight that area in my text editor.

Does ANTLR provide any means of obtaining that information (an expression's position and length within the document being parsed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expression.getStart()` to get the first token of your expression and then `.getLine()` and `getCharPositionInLine()` to get the line and column number respectively.

To get the length, you can subtract the start index of the first token from the stop index of the last token and then add 1 (because both indices are inclusive, so an expression of length 1 would have the same start and stop index pointing to the single character that makes up the expression).

Note that the more obvious solution of `expression.getText().length()` won't include skipped tokens in the length.

Comment: So there is a corresponding expression.getStop() method?

Comment: @SongWatcher Yes, there's `getStart()` for the first token and `getStop()` for the last. You can find all available methods (except the ones generated from your grammar, that is) [in the ANTLR API docs](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ParserRuleContext.html).

Comment: I see. So, if I understand things, ANTLR will use my grammar file to generate a parser that implements a version of the Visitor Pattern, with methods for accepting the various expressions defined in my grammar. Each expression will possess these getStart() and getStop() methods automatically?

Comment: @SongWatcher Right. More precisely: From your grammar, ANTLR will generate FooContext classes that make up a parse tree, a parser class that can be used to create such a parse tree and listener and/or visitor base classes that can be used to traverse such a tree. Each branch in the tree (i.e. each expression and sub-expression when you're parsing expressions) will be an instance of such a generated class and it will have all the methods available on `ParserRuleContext`.

Comment: Sepp2k, thank you so much for answers that even exceeded my expectations.